# Application to meassure DLL load time?

Tags: dll

Is there any application/tool that I can use to meassure how long time each DLL takes to load when the exe-file starts up?

I've got an exe file (C++/MFC) that takes several seconds until the first line of code is reached, loading linked DLL files is what I expect takes time, so it would be useful to meassure that time.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a profiler, it tells you whether it is code that causes the delay.  If it is not then just is the file system, having to dig around for DLL files.  Otherwise easy to tell, if it starts up quickly the second time then it is the file system.

Comment: Yes, I know it's the file system, since second time is fast. But I want to diagnose what parts of the file system that takes time. The app loads about 20 DLL files, and I would like to see the time each DLL took to load during a cold startup, and I don't think a profiler will show that..?